# Django on docker container returns localhost as domain in production server

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I have been following this tutorial here [Dockerize Django](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/) to dockerize my django application with Nginx as production web server. However inside my django code get_current_site(request).domain returns localhost as a result all generated url endpoints have the domain localhost instead of the production server domain name.
my nginx.conf: [here](https://pastebin.com/1BkvH52r)

```
upstream fullstack_application {
   server web:8000;
}

server {

listen 80;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://fullstack_application;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
}


   location /static/ {
        alias /home/app/web/static/;
   }

  location /media/ {
     alias /home/app/web/media/;
  }

}
```

my production docker-compose.yml: [here](https://pastebin.com/u9QFVd5J)

```
version: "3.7"

services:
        web:
           build:
               context: ./app
               dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
           command: gunicorn fullstack_application.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
           volumes:
                   - static_volume:/home/app/web/static
                   - media_volume:/home/app/web/media
           expose:
              - 8000
           env_file:
              - ./.env.prod
           depends_on:
              - db
       db:
           image: postgres:12.0-alpine
          volumes:
              - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
          env_file:
              - ./.env.prod.db
      nginx:
          build: ./nginx
          volumes:
             - static_volume:/home/app/web/static
             - media_volume:/home/app/web/media
          ports:
             - 1337:80
          depends_on:
             - web
     volumes:
        postgres_data:
        static_volume:
        media_volume:
```

Pls help :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `hostname` and/or `domainname` for service `web` in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

See [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir).